# Catching Django Errors When Client Is Not A Web Browser?

Tags: django, logging, exception, fastcgi, lighttpd

I'm building a Django web service that is called from an application.  When it throws an exception, I can't see the Django debug page, and can't get to it because the calling application doesn't behave like a web browser (and I don't have control over that application).

Is there a way to redirect the Django error page to a a log file rather than to the calling client, possibly via changing the FastCGI config (I'm using lighty + FastCGI)?  Or maybe a "dump to file" config option or some sort of LogExceptionToFile() method within the framework itself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might try just creating custom ExceptionMiddleware. Just change the process_exception method to log the exception and request data somewhere.

Here's an example: http://www.peterbe.com/plog/who-was-logged-in-during-a-django-exception

Answer (score 0):

If the exception in the django app is not caught, and `DEBUG = True`, then the exception should be sent to the client.

Some options to help you get debugging info:

- [Enable and configure logging](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/logging/)
- [Set up email error reporting](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/error-reporting/)
- Use something like [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) to inspect the HTTP request and responses.